# How can I check a file for an IndexOutOfRangeException and log it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, error-handling

**UPDATE**

```
try
        {
            //Attemps string conversion for each of the point's variables
            int.TryParse(row[0], out q.pointID); //Checks for existence of data on the line...
            float.TryParse(row[1], out q.xValue); //Input x-value
            float.TryParse(row[2], out q.yValue); //Input y-value
            float.TryParse(row[3], out q.zValue); //Input z-value
            float.TryParse(row[4], out q.tempValue); //Input temp-value
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            Debug.Log("File out of range...");
            errorLogScript.errorCode = 1100;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(4);
        }
```

This is the current code that I have but it seems to be freezing whenever I attempt to transfer the scene to the errorScreen. That being said, I am not getting an error but my code is freezing and Unity crashes whenever I attempt to test this bug.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

**OP**

I am currently working on an application in Unity and I wanted to create a bug/crash-reporting system that shows the user a unique error code upon a failure to load. Being that this specific application will be used by many people with many different skill-sets, I wanted to break it as much as I can before I release it later this year. In doing so I wanted to make a quick reference that the user will be able to look up in the documentation.

*The following code demostrates what happens if the user-input filepath does not exist...*

```
if (File.Exists(dropDownMenuScript.dataFileName + ".csv"))
    {
        Debug.Log("File found, loading..."); //Debugs success to console
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("File not found, aborting..."); //Debugs the problem to console
        errorLogScript.errorCode = 1000; //Shows the code "E1000"
        SceneManager.LoadScene(4); //Loads the error-screen which displays the code
    }
```

I recently found another error that reads; "IndexOutOfRangeException" -- in this case this pertains to the parsing of the file, meaning it exists but it does not conform to the data format compatible with the program. I would like to create another error-log for this problem but I do know how to do this as it is a Unity Editor error.

I apologize if this isn't crystal-clear, but I will provide any context needed if you need it. Thanks!

Comment: use try catch to handle exceptions

Comment: Can't you use a try-catch block and specifically traps for IndexOutOfRangeException?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use a try-catch block and specifically traps for IndexOutOfRangeException?

```
try
{
    //Your code...
}
catch(IndexOutOfRangeException iore)
{
    //Log here
}
```